# How to find the sum of numbers that have digits higher than 5

Tags: c++

so I want to write a function that returns the sum of all numbers in an array who's digits are higher then 5 so for example if the array is [12, 66, 23, 67] the answer would be 66+67
This code summs all the numbers in the array and I can'\t figure out why

````
using namespace std;
int func(int n[], int size){
    int digit, S=0, a;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

      a= n[i];

        while( n[i]!=0){

            digit= n[i]%10;

                  if(digit>=5){

                       n[i]= n[i]/10;


                    }
         else break;

        }
        S=S+a;

    }

 return S;   
}

int main()
{
    int n[3], i;

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
       cin>>n[i];


   }

   cout<<func(n, 3)<<endl;
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Think about `a= n[i];` and `S=S+a`. I also recommend that you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

`S=S+a` This piece of code is ***out of your while loop and inside for loop***, this will add all the elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not checking ***when*** you should add `a` to `S`.
These lines are causing the problem:

```
int func(int n[], int size){
    int digit, S=0, a;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      a= n[i];
      while( n[i]!=0){
          digit= n[i]%10;
          if(digit>=5){    // Wrong. Do "digit > 5"
              n[i]= n[i]/10;
          }
          else break;      <--- exiting this while loop
      }
      S=S+a;               <--- ...but still adding?
    }
    return S;   
}
```

You are breaking the loop, but *still* adding to the sum.
You should use a flag. Your inner loop would look something like this:

```
// We need to check if each digit is valid
bool each_digit_greater_than_5 = true;

// As long as we have digits left and all previous digits were valid
while(n[i] != 0 && each_digit_greater_than_5)
{
    // Extract a digit
    digit = n[i] % 10;

    // If valid, get next digit to extract
    if(digit > 5)
    {
        n[i] /= 10;
    }
    // Else, exit the loop
    else
    {
        each_digit_greater_than_5 = false;
    }
}
```

And then, simply check if `each_digit_greater_than_5`:

```
// If number was valid
if(each_digit_greater_than_5)
{
    // Add to sum
    S = S + a;
}
```

---

### Extra Notes:

*How you write* the code is often more important than *what* you write.
Here are (some) food for thoughts.

- ***Use better formatting***: The whole block of code should be uniformly indented. This:

```
...
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      a= n[i];
        while( n[i]!=0){
            digit= n[i]%10;
...
```

is both confusing and unclear. Use same indentation for each separate block:

```
...
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){         // The base block
    a= n[i];                       // new block start, add indent
    while( n[i]!=0){               // same block, same indent
        digit= n[i]%10;            // new block, add indent
...
```

- ***Use better naming***: Don't use `S`, `a` and `n` unless they are very clear.
  `digit` is a good choice, so credits for that!
  Here, it is better to use:

```
sum_of_special_numbers
```

and

```
array
```

and

```
current_number
```

instead of `S`, `n` and `a`.

- ***Comment!***: Another very important part of programming (Note: not coding).
  Are you coding?

```
Don't care if anyone understands it or not, just doing it cause they said so.
```

Or programming?

```
Making a clear, maintainable and debuggable code.
```

You decide!

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged with C++, I want to give an additional answer that uses C++ and especially modern C++ algorithms. I added also comments to the code and used meaningful variable names. I recommend that you try to do the same in the future.

What is the example code doing?

First, it informs the user about the software and asks, how many values should be checked and added. The values will be stored in a `std::vector`. With `std::copy_n` and the `std::istream_iterator` we read the values given by the user. The `std::istream_iterator` simply calls the extractor operator `>>` in the copy loop.

Then we call the subfunction to calculate the sum and show it to the user.

The subfunction consists of one Lampda definition and one `std::accumulate` statement. That's all.

The lambda converts the int to a `std::string` and then checks if any of the characters in the number is lower than '5'. Then it returns an inverted result.

So, you see, with C++, the implementation get's very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int sumOfNumbersWithDigitsGreaterThan5(const std::vector<int>& v) {

    // Create a lambda that checks, if all digits are greater than 5
    auto check5 = [](const int i) -> bool { std::string s{ std::to_string(i) };
                    return !std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](const char c) { return c <= '5'; }); };

    // Calculate the sume of all given values in the vector with all digits greater than 5
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, 
        [&](const int init, const int i) { return init + (check5(i) ? i : 0); });
}

int main() {
    // Inform the user, what to do
    std::cout << "Sum of all numbers having all digits greater than 5\n\nHow many numbers to you want to sum?:  ";

    // Get the number of values that we want to sum up. Check plausibility
    if (int numberOfValuesToCheck{}; (std::cin >> numberOfValuesToCheck) && (numberOfValuesToCheck > 0)) {

        // Create a std::vector for our values having the requested number of elements
        std::vector<int> values(numberOfValuesToCheck);

        // Read the requested number of elements from std::cin to the values vector
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfValuesToCheck, values.begin());

        // Show result
        std::cout << "\n\nThe sum for all numbers with all digits greater 5 is:  " <<
            sumOfNumbersWithDigitsGreaterThan5(values) << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Wrong input\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are many many other possible solutions . . .